# Laravel controller won't let me passing data as a json for with the error : Call to a member function withData() on string

Tags: json, laravel, controller

hi guys im stuck here i dont know whay i cant send json data with a laravel controller.

controller :

```
        $data =  DB::table('users')
        ->where('id','=',$id)
        ->get();

        // dd($data);Working perfectly
        return '/medcine/homeMS'->withData(json_encode($data));//error in this line
```

my route :

```
Route::get('/medcine/homeMS', function () {
return view('auth.medcine.homeMS');
})->middleware('verified')->middleware('medcineMS');
```

and in my blade i added this line :

```
        <div data={{$data}} ></div>
```

Comment: You have to return a view, not a string `return view('your-view-name')->withData(json_encode($data));`

Comment: already tried it and it give me this error : Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.  and i searched in the net and i found the solution is to return string :(

Comment: check out this [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses)

Comment: If you don't have a view but just want to return JSON you can use `return response()->json($data);` On the other hand, your route doesn't use a Controller, so ... either change your route to use your controller@method or add your controller code to your route function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not configured your route correctly

in the second parameter you should specify your controller
route:

```
Route::get('/medcine/homeMS', "YourController@method")->middleware('verified')->middleware('medcineMS');
```

and in your controller:

```
 $data =  DB::table('users')
        ->where('id','=',$id)
        ->get();

        return view('auth.medcine.homeMS')->with('data' , json_encode($data));
```